# Error while creating new angular application(npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/animations@~7.1.0.)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm having windows 10,node v11.0.0 and Angular CLI: 7.1.4 and  facing this error while creating an new angular application. npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/animations@~7.1.0.

Error stack:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\Software\\node-v11.0.0-win-x64\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Software\\node-v11.0.0-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--quiet' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v11.0.0
4 verbose npm-session 56bc1a48a2be70ea
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall myapp@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~preinstall: myapp@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 12ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 3ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree

**Packaage.json :**

{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: check your internet connection, maybe just a dependency issue.

Comment: Can you also share you package.json details?

Comment: I have included pacakage.json file content.

Answer (score 0):

1. This could be because the `@angular/animations` is not defined in
   your package.json.

   Please make sure you add it to your `package.json` dependencies and
   install npm dependencies.
2. If it is already added, please delete your `package-lock.json` and
   reinstall `npm` dependencies ( `npm install`).
3. Also if it's already installed in project dependencies (node_modules dir), make sure
   you import it in the `AppModule` or wherever it's being used (any
   child module).